# The delete button doesn’t wait for confirmation on iOS

Tags: bug, user-interface, vote-to-delete, mobile-safari

On iOS (Safari iOS 16.5), when I vote to delete a question or answer, an alert appears asking if I’m sure. However, the page refreshes out from under the alert, and the vote is recorded — in some cases, *deleting the post even when I click “Cancel”.*

[image]

In this image, I deleted the answer, and then later voted to delete the question, too. I left the third VTD on the question, so it was deleted (as evidenced by the red background) — yet the confirmation alert is still visible, and I haven’t interacted with it.

This is especially bad because “Delete” is right next to “Edit” on my own posts. The other day, I fat-fingered the edit button, and deleted my own answer on accident.

Comment: "deleted my own answer on accident" — Not quite so bad as voting to delete other people's answers. As a mod frequently on mobile, this freaks me out.

Comment: This is the case for chat too